# what is Eclipse workSpace master

Tags: eclipse

i didn't have seen

what does mean? 
 and not influence to any project ? 
It'is Bother

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgHRT.png)

Comment: This is probably something to do with whichever source control system you are using (Git, SVN, ....)

Comment: Oh thanks lots ... it to help me